# How to mix forms auth in Piranha

Tags: piranha-cms

I am integrating Piranha into an existing web application which already has SimpleMembership implemented and I am running into issues with being logged into Piranha and then attempting to use my app. Is there any way to make Piranha use my authentication mechanism?

Comment: What issues are you getting ? Specifically what fails to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Piranha CMS doesn't integrate to other authentication providers. There is an existing feature request for this that is planned to be implemented. However replacing the security layer is a tedious task so I can't give you an exact date for when it will be done.

Regards

Håkan